# esp8266 wifi BearSSL Secure Server Class

Tags: security, ssl, server, wifi, esp8266

I want to use setBufferSizes for BearSSL Secure Server Class which is mentioned here:
https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/server-class.html
I am not sure how to do it and I couldn`t find any document about this application. can annyone help me about this?

Comment: Maybe you can look at the BearSSL _client_ example at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/BearSSL_MaxFragmentLength/BearSSL_MaxFragmentLength.ino and apply the same tweaks to the server.

Comment: thank you but i want to use it on ESP8266WebServer and i donot know how to work with client in that library

Answer (score 0):

I found the soloution:
In setting we write :
server.getServer().setBufferSizes(2048,2048);
before:
server.begin();